# Kibana is not showing any values of .raw fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4

i am using kibana 4 and it is showing .raw field i.e result.raw in list of fields along with result.
i have checked my elasticsearch indices mapping and they are also showing raw fields.
then why kiban is not showing any values of those raw field(It was showing from past 15 days but yesterday i put some more grok pattern in my logstash config file from that time it stopped showing me those value. Now it is not showing .raw field value for past data as well and the pattern i put was working fine and giving analyzed field value but not .raw field)

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/logstash-2015.09.25?pretty'<br><br>
   {
     "logstash-2015.09.25" : {
         "aliases" : { },
         "mappings" : {
         "_default_" : {
         "dynamic_templates" : [ {
         "message_field" : {
         "mapping" : {
         "index" : "analyzed",
         "omit_norms" : true,
         "type" : "string"
        },
        "match" : "message",
        "match_mapping_type" : "string"
      }
    }, {
      "string_fields" : {
        "mapping" : {
          "index" : "analyzed",
          "omit_norms" : true,
          "type" : "string",
          "fields" : {
            "raw" : {
              "index" : "not_analyzed",
              "ignore_above" : 256,
              "type" : "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "match" : "*",
        "match_mapping_type" : "string"
      }
    } ],
    "_all" : {
      "enabled" : true,
      "omit_norms" : true
    },
    "properties" : {
      "@version" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed"
      },
      "geoip" : {
        "dynamic" : "true",
        "properties" : {
          "location" : {
            "type" : "geo_point"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "scan_production" : {
    "dynamic_templates" : [ {
      "message_field" : {
        "mapping" : {
          "index" : "analyzed",
          "omit_norms" : true,
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "match" : "message",
        "match_mapping_type" : "string"
      }
    }, {
      "string_fields" : {
        "mapping" : {
          "index" : "analyzed",
          "omit_norms" : true,
          "type" : "string",
          "fields" : {
            "raw" : {
              "index" : "not_analyzed",
              "ignore_above" : 256,
              "type" : "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "match" : "*",
        "match_mapping_type" : "string"
      }
    } ],
    "_all" : {
      "enabled" : true,
      "omit_norms" : true
    },
    "properties" : {
      "@timestamp" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
      },
      "@version" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed"
      },
      "command" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "file" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "geoip" : {
        "dynamic" : "true",
        "properties" : {
          "location" : {
            "type" : "geo_point"
          }
        }
      },
      "host" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "id" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "message" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        }
      },
      "message_type" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "offset" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "received_at" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
      },
      "received_from" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "result" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "severity" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "tags" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
      "timestamp" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
      },
      "type" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "norms" : {
          "enabled" : false
        },
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
"settings" : {
  "index" : {
    "creation_date" : "1443139268796",
    "uuid" : "qJyyA60ZSpGY2CuBfoG8JQ",
    "number_of_replicas" : "1",
    "number_of_shards" : "5",
    "refresh_interval" : "5s",
    "version" : {
      "created" : "1040599"
    }
  }
},
"warmers" : { }
  }
 }
```

cat /etc/logstash/conf.d/lumberjack.conf

```
input {
  lumberjack {
  port => 5000
  type => "logs"
  ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
  ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
   }
   }

       filter {
 if [type] == "scan_production" {

 if "LISTING_SCRAPER SUCCESS" in [message]{
    grok{
  match => { "message" => "(?<severity>[E]|[W]|%{GREEDYDATA})\, +\[(?   <timestamp>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}) \#(?<id>%{INT})\] +%{WORD:message_type} \-\- \: (?<command>%{DATA}\:|%{DATA}\:%{NOTSPACE}) %{NOTSPACE:site_name} \location: (?<location_id>%{INT}|%{SPACE}) time\:\ %{BASE10NUM:site_access_time:float}" }
  add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
  add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
  }
 mutate {
  convert => ["site_access_time", "float"]
  }
}

  else if "LISTING_CRAWLER SUCCESS site" in [message]{
    grok{
  match => { "message" => "(?<severity>[E]|[W]|%{GREEDYDATA})\, +\[(?<timestamp>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}) \#(?<id>%{INT})\] +%{WORD:message_type} \-\- \: (?<command>%{DATA}\:|%{DATA}\:%{NOTSPACE}) %{NOTSPACE:site_name} \location: (?<location_id>%{INT}|%{SPACE}) time\:\ %{BASE10NUM:site_access_time:float} items\: %{BASE10NUM:location_iteam:float}" }
  add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
  add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
  }
 mutate {
   convert => ["site_access_time", "float"]
 }
 }
else{
 grok {
match => { "message" => "(?<severity>[E]|[W]|%{GREEDYDATA})\, +\[(? <timestamp>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}) \#(?<id>%{INT})\] +%{WORD:message_type} \-\- \: (?<command>%{DATA}\:|%{DATA}\:%{NOTSPACE}) %{GREEDYDATA:result}" }
  add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
  add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
         }
       }
     }
   }


output {
 elasticsearch { host => localhost
    protocol => http
}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
 }
```